# Вытащить слово из текста регуляркой

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, get

Из кода:

```
<td><strong>Ник в игре</strong></td>
    <td>Nickname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Ник на форуме</strong></td>
    <td>Forumname</td>
</tr>
```

Регуляркой надо выдернуть слова `Nickname` и `Forumname`. Прошу помощи..

Comment: Чёрт, некорректно немного составил сообщение.. Вот код:
<td><strong>Ник в игре</strong></td>
 <td>Nickname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><strong>Ник на форуме</strong></td>
 <td>Forumname</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вот вариант регулярного выражения

```
/<\/strong><\/td>\s<td>([\s\S]+?)<\/td>/
```